# Laravel 5.7 - Eloquent Query that checks if not equal to id or null AND not equal to another id and a team_id not in (?, ?)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, orm, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to create a scope on my model that queries for results that are not related to user based on the following possibilities:
1. The `assigned_user_id` is not null and `reported_by` doesn't match and any of the user's team_ids (one-to-many user to teams) match the `assigned_team_id`
AND 
2. The `assigned_user_id` does not match and `reported_by` doesn't match and any of the user's team_ids (one-to-many user to teams) match the `assigned_team_id`

The only tricky part for me really is that the assigned_user_id is nullable. assigned_team_id is required and reported_by is required. This is my current attempt:

```
public function scopeNotRelativeTo($query, User $user)
{
    $teamIDs = $user->teams->pluck('id');

    $query->whereNull('assigned_user_id')
          ->orWhere('assigned_user_id', '!=', $user->id)
          ->where('reported_by', '!=', $user->id)
          ->whereNotIn('assigned_team_id', $teamIDs);
}
```

This is returning 46 results and I am expecting 41, so it's not quite right. The `toSql()` is

```
"select * from \"bugs\" where (\"assigned_user_id\" is null or \"assigned_user_id\" != ? and \"reported_by\" != ? and \"assigned_team_id\" not in (?, ?)) and \"bugs\".\"deleted_at\" is null order by \"created_at\" desc"
```

which looks close, but it is still clearly imperfect. I can definitely see that there are results slipping through the cracks with matching team_ids mostly. Pseudo code version would be `Give me results where the assigned_user_id is not null AND reported_by doesn't match userId AND assigned_team_id not in user->teamIds OR assigned_user_id doesn't match userId AND reported_by doesn't match userId and assigned_team_id is not in user->teamIds`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL and most programming languages split conditions on `OR`.

Meaning, in your query and pseudocode, you're actually asking:

```
where the assigned_user_id is null 
OR
where assigned_user_id = ? AND reported_by doesn't match ? AND assigned_team_id not in (?, ?)
```

What you probably want is to logically contain your OR condition, which is done by parentheses in SQL or nested closures in Eloquent:

```
$query->where(function($q) {
           $q->whereNull('assigned_user_id')
             ->orWhere('assigned_user_id', '!=', $user->id);
      })
      ->where('reported_by', '!=', $user->id)
      ->whereNotIn('assigned_team_id', $teamIDs);
```